# How to get the all the reviews of the product posted by the customer in magento 2

Tags: php, collection, frontend, magento2.2, product-review

I have removed **review tab** and placed my **review form** as a **popup** modal in **product page**.How to get the **all the reviews** of the product **posted** by the **customer** in **Product page**.Now I need to get all the **reviews collection** and want to displayed it in product page. Please provide me a solution

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">XXX_YYY::review.phtml</argument>
            </action>

            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.review.popup" template="XXX_YYY::popup.phtml">

                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="custom.product.review.form" as="custom.review_form" template="XXX_YYY::form.phtml">
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                </block>
            </block>

        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true" />
        </referenceBlock>
        <!--Created new section before the footer-->
        <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
            <container name="custom.product.section">
                <block class="XXX_YYY\Block\Form" name="custom.product.section.info" template="XXX_YYY::abc.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: have you need on product view page?

Comment: Yes in product view page

Comment: Please refer this link to provide a solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205263/how-to-add-a-custom-block-before-footer-section-in-product-page-in-magento-2

Answer (score 2):

**Look this block file :** /vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/View.php

**In this file, Magento create the function** getReviewsCollection()

```
public function getReviewsCollection()
{
    if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
        $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $this->getProduct()->getId()
        )->setDateOrder();
    }
    return $this->_reviewsCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all the reviews for a particular product in the product page, you have to include the following block in your `catalog_product_view.xml` file.

Step-1)

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="Path to your template file"/>
```

Step-2)

In your `template"` file, add the following code,

```
$_items     =   $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
$format     =   $block->getDateFormat() ?: \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT;
$review     =   array();
if (count($_items)) {

    foreach ($_items as $_review){

        if (count($_review->getRatingVotes())) {
            foreach ($_review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote) {
                $rating_vote =  $_vote->getPercent();
                $rating_code =  $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode());
            }
        } else {
            $rating_vote = 0;
            $rating_code = '';
        }

        $review[] =     array(
                            'title'             =>  $block->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()), 
                            'review-text'       =>  $block->escapeHtml($_review->getDetail()),
                            'review-by-title'   =>  __('Review by'),
                            'rating-code'       =>  $rating_code,
                            'review-by'         =>  $block->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname()),
                            'rating-value'      =>  $rating_vote,
                            'review-date'       =>  $block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format)
                        );

    }

}

$content['item']            =   $review;
$content['review-count']    =   count($_items);
$content['review-title']    =   __('Customer Reviews');

echo $content ;
```

Step-3)

In your Product Page phtml, access the reviews as follows,

```
$review_array                   =   $this->getChildHtml('product_review');
```

Print the `$review_array` and you can see all reviews.

Comment: In step 1, you have mentioned the core template file as list .phtml, Now In step 2 you told to add the code what you mentioned in list.phtml. But list.phtml is a core file how could i add your code in that

Comment: You told me to do override

Comment: See my post, I have already added a custom container for showing the reviews. If I am wrong Please correct me

Comment: You don't have to use or override Magento_Review::product/view/list.phtml. You can use whatever phtml file you want, but you have to bind the block Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView to your phtml. Then in your phtml file , use the function $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems(); to get all the reviews.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file, you can add a block using the different unique identifier.

You can add the review block again using a different name

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="reviews.list" as="reviews.list" template="Magento_Review::review.phtml" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have created the section to display the customer reviews ,Please see the updated post

Comment: In my code i need to call customer reviews collection in abc.phtml from the block

Comment: Add above block in your prefered container with updating the path `template="XXX_YYY::abc.phtml" `

Comment: I have added the block ,But how to get the reviews collection in block

Comment: <container name="custom.product.section">
            <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Product\Review" name="custom.product.section.info" template="XXX_YYY::abc.phtml"/>
        </container>

Comment: Please see the updated post @Salma Saiyad

Comment: use this in your block constructor
(\Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,){
$this->_reviewsColFactory = $collectionFactory;}

 $collection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
        )->addStatusFilter(
            \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
        )->addEntityFilter(
            'product',
            $this->getProductId()
        );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70091/discussion-between-jayashree-and-salma-saiyad).

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $_productsreviewFactory;

public function __construct(
Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory $productsreviewFactory){
$this->_productsreviewFactory = $productsreviewFactory;}

$collection = $this->_productsreviewFactory->create();

return $collection->getData();
```